# SSH timing out - no longer able to access server after installing Fail2ban

Tags: ssh, fail2ban

I decided to improve security on my Ubuntu 20.04 server by installing fail2ban.  Looks like I went too far :/

I was previously logging in fine using SSH.

I installed a default fail2ban install, copied the jail and and fail2ban configs to duplicated .local files, added my IP to the whitelist and then walked away and had lunch with the SSH connection open.

During the setup I ran the following command for the firewall which I'm concerned about:

```
ufw allow ssh
ufw enable
```

I was going to add a custom jail for OpenVPN (which is what the server uses).

Upon returning to the machine after lunch and trying to reconnect via SSH, the connection times out with the following:

> ssh -v user@mynoiphostname.mynoipdomain.net -p myport OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to mynoiphostname.mynoipdomain.net port (myport).
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

The server still runs fine - I can still use the OpenVPN service.

I've tried to connect using SSH via 3 different IP addresses - each give the same result.  I assume I've properly locked myself out now and won't be able to SSH back in?

The server can be accessed physically, but the people accessing it will be even less computer savvy than I am!  Can I please confirm that if they input the following commands they should be able to remove the fail2ban config so that I can SSH in again and sort this out by uninstalling fail2ban and starting again?

```
sudo su
sudo fail2ban-client stop
sudo systemctl stop fail2ban
```

I can't get to the server physically myself due to covid.

Any clues as to what I did wrong would be great too.

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is `myport`? Unless you modified the application profile, then `ufw allow ssh` would only have opened the *default* SSH port (port 22), I think

Comment: I've restricted ssh access to a particular port, which I masked in the above.

So the command I typed was e.g.

`ssh -v user@server.net -p 33333`

and in the response it would read:

`debug1: connecting to server.net port 33333`

This was working fine prior to the fail2ban installation, and I'm certain I'm using the same port as before - the connection string is saved as an alias.

Comment: God almighty, it never ceases to amaze me the people and the times I have read change the port idea. Like them bots that scan everything in existence multiple times a day 24/7/365. They are so stupid they do not think to try different ports...

Comment: How long does it take to scan all ports?  The guide I followed suggested using a weird, high one, the idea being that a lot of bots would only scan the defaults?
Interestingly, trying to connect back at 22 gives a different failure - it seems to go through but fails because I've only allowed key access.

The only failure seems to be when trying the specific port I've left open for ssh - worth looking in the ssh config file first?